# How is the number of random walks determined in GDS/Neo4j?

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I am running the random walk algorithm on my Neo4j graph named 'example', with the minimum allowed walk length (2) and walks per node (1). Namely,

```
CALL gds.beta.randomWalk.stream(
  'example',
  {
    walkLength: 2,
    walksPerNode: 1,
    randomSeed: 42,
    concurrency: 1
  }
)
YIELD nodeIds, path
RETURN nodeIds, [node IN nodes(path) | node.name ] AS event_name
```

And I get 41 walks. How is this number determined? I checked the graph and it contains 161 nodes and 574 edges. Any insights?

Added later: Here is more info on the projected graph that I am constructing. Basically, I am filtering on nodes and relationships and just projecting the subgraph and doing nothing else. Here is the code -

```
// Filter for only IDH Codel recurrent events
WITH [path=(m:IDHcodel)--(n:Tissue)
WHERE (m.node_category = 'molecular' AND n.event_class = 'Recurrence')
AND NOT EXISTS((m)--(:Tissue{event_class:'Primary'})) | m] AS recur_events
// Obtain the sub-network with 2 or more patients in edges
MATCH p=(m1)-[r:hasIDHcodelPatients]-(m2)
WHERE (m1 IN recur_events AND m2 IN recur_events AND r.total_common_patients >= 2)
WITH COLLECT(p) AS all_paths
WITH [p IN all_paths | nodes(p)] AS path_nodes, [p IN all_paths | relationships(p)] AS path_rels
WITH apoc.coll.toSet(apoc.coll.flatten(path_nodes)) AS subgraph_nodes, apoc.coll.flatten(path_rels) AS subgraph_rels

// Form the GDS Cypher projection
CALL gds.graph.create.cypher(
'example',
'MATCH (n) where n in $sn RETURN id(n) as id',
'MATCH ()-[r]-() where r in $sr RETURN id(startNode(r)) as source , id(endNode(r)) as target, { LINKS: { orientation: "UNDIRECTED" } }',
{parameters: {sn: subgraph_nodes, sr: subgraph_rels} }
)
YIELD graphName AS graph, nodeQuery, nodeCount AS nodes, relationshipQuery, relationshipCount AS rels
RETURN graph, nodes, rels
```

Thanks.

Comment: please show us how you created "example" graph using gds and how you created your 161 nodes/574 edges graph. thanks.

Comment: @jose_bacoy Thanks. Added the code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the documentation is missing the description for the `sourceNodes` parameter, which would tell you how many walks will be created.
We don't know the default value, but we can use the parameter to set the source nodes that the walk should start from.

For example, you could use all the nodes in the graph to be treated as a source node (the random walk will start from them).

```
MATCH (n)
WITH collect(n) AS nodes
CALL gds.beta.randomWalk.stream(
  'example',
  { sourceNodes:nodes,
    walkLength: 2,
    walksPerNode: 1,
    randomSeed: 42,
    concurrency: 1
  }
)
YIELD nodeIds, path
RETURN nodeIds, [node IN nodes(path) | node.name ] AS event_name
```

This way you should get 161 walks as there are 161 nodes in your graph and the `walksPerNode` is set to 1, so a single random walk will start from every node in the graph. In essence, the number of source nodes times the walks per node will determine the number of random walks.

Comment: I don't think that's an issue. I tried with the sourceNodes like you describe and it throws an error saying ```Failed to invoke procedure `gds.beta.randomWalk.stream`: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Source nodes do not exist in the in-memory graph: ['10000', '10001', '10002', '10003'...]``` Please note I have added all my query above. Thanks.

Comment: The docs were updated, by default the random walk starts from every node.

Comment: Great! Thanks for letting me know.